# Import obj model: pictures with the same name will only be imported once

Tags: python

I am importing obj model in batch with script

This is my code:
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=obj_path)

Obj paths are in different folders, and they have the same image name,After importing, the picture with the same name will only be imported once, and other objects will use this picture

Here is my example:

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

They all use the same picture name,After importing[image]
[image]

Comment: that is a bug most likely related to the issue report I have opened https://developer.blender.org/T100361